# Netplan - Multiple ssids with different static IP on the same interface

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan

I have successfully set up a wifi network configuration like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlxf8d1111b0d78:
      addresses: [10.0.0.69/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.138
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        WIFI_NAME_HERE:
          password: PASS_HERE
```

What I want to achieve is add another SSID to which I want the interface to get a different static ip (192.168.1.69) with a different gateway (192.168.1.1).

Can someone help me on how to achieve this? The various examples I've read have not answered this question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively this is not supported through netplan.  You can instead set `renderer: NetworkManager` and use your netplan config as a seed of initial configuration to NetworkManager, then manage the IP settings through NetworkManager directly.

Comment: Could you describe the process please?

Comment: I've clarified how you would go about changing your netplan config to feed to NM instead of networkd.  Beyond that, managing IP settings through NM is probably best done through the GUI tools.

Comment: Thanks @slangasek for the answer

Comment: Can you reference any official documentation to that fact?